# Wix Bootstrapper is cancelled when UAC "Change when these notifications appear" is clicked

Tags: wix, uac, bootstrapper

I've created a Wix Bootstrapper (v3.11) that install .NET 4.5 and then some MSI with my application. After checking the license agreement check-box and clicking Install button the UAC dialog pops up (which is expected).

However, if in the UAC dialog you click **Show more details** link and then click **Change when these notifications appear** link your installer will be cancelled and you will get a pop up dialog saying **"User cancelled installation."**

[User cancelled installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPf7Q.jpg)

Is there a way to prevent the installation to be cancelled and so the error dialog to be pop up?

Here is a simple Bundle.wxs sample that reproduces the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Bundle Name="Dummy_Setup_for_UAC_Test"
        Version="1.0.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Tester"
        UpgradeCode="37561e88-cadf-4b9c-94c3-5510325e51d2">

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef 
           Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click `Change when these notifications appear`, Windows cancels the elevation request. That's true for any UAC consent prompt. So it's not something you can change for a bundle.

Comment: Thanks @Bob, I didn't know that. I've reproduced that scenario using some third part installers and cancelling the installation seems to be the standard behavior when user clicks **Change when these notifications appear**. I hope it were possible to catch the UAC response for providing a better user experience in that scenario. Thanks for your help.